# How to make Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.DataRepeater instantly update bound data?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datarepeater

Here I'm talking about Windows Forms Application written in C#. Consider a simple model

```
class Labelled
{
    private string label;
    public string Label
    {
        get { return label; }
        set
        {
            if (label != value)
            {
                string message = String.Format(
                    "Label changed from {0} to {1}",
                    label, value
                );
                MessageBox.Show(message);
                label = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public Labelled(string label)
    {
        this.label = label;
    }
}

class Model
{
    public Labelled SingularLabelled { get; set; }

    public List<Labelled> ListedLabelled { get; set; }

    public Model()
    {
        SingularLabelled = new Labelled("Singular");

        ListedLabelled = new List<Labelled>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
            ListedLabelled.Add(new Labelled("Listed " + i.ToString()));
    }
}
```

We have a simple class `Labelled` with string property `Label` and class `Model` with member `SingularLabelled` of type `Labelled` and `ListedLabelled` which is a list of `Labelled`'s.

Now I want to display the data to the user. Here is my setup:

[image: Main window and data bindings]

The main window has a `TextBox` for displaying `SingularLabelled.Label` and a `DataRepeater` from the Visual Basic PowerPacks to display labels of the elements of `ListedLabelled`. The `ItemTemplate` of the `DataRepeater` consists of just a single `TextBox`.

Let's focus on one way binding, namely I want the underlying data to be updated when the User changes the contents of a text box. The `Label` property of the `Labelled` raises a notification in form of a message box, so I can get to know exactly when the data is being updated. Now the arrows represent bindings. Blue arrows stand for data source and the red ones for data members. An instance of `Model` is created and bound to the `modelBindingSource` in the constructor of the main window form.

And here we come to a very important thing. I want the data to be updated *immediately* in sync with what the User is typing, so I made sure that the data source update modes of the data bindings are set to `OnPropertyChanged`. The generated code that might be of interest here is

```
this.singularTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.modelBindingSource, "SingularLabelled.Label", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
this.listedTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.listedLabelledBindingSource, "Label", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

And this is working as expected when typing into the text box of `SingularLabelled` but the text boxes within `DataRepeater` trigger the update only when they loose focus. I want them to behave like the singular one. Ideal solution would be to do it using the designer. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image: SingularLabelled label update]

[image: ListedLabelled label update]

Above is a sample of the program working. Notice how `SingularLabelled`'s label is updated every character put in and the members of `ListedLabelled` get the whole edited chunk updated after the corresponding text box looses focus.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to overcome this limitation of DataRepeater by simulating the Tab key.

```
    private void listedTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //simulate tab key to force databinding
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        SendKeys.Send("+{TAB}");
    }
```

Comment: That's an interresting proposition. Nevertheless for now I just dropped the `DataRepeater` and assembled my own control similar to it that doesn't have that problem.